# How to replace each word once

Tags: c#, asp.net

For Example: "I'm a **word**. change my **char** to new **word**"

i want replace "word" to "char" and replace "char" to "word"

result :"I'm a **char**. change my **word** to new **char**"

It is very important to me

so thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to match both words, so that you replace them in the same call. That way you avoid the problem with multiple replacements interfering with each other:

```
str = Regex.Replace(str, "(char|word)", m => m.Groups[0].Value == "char" ? "word" : "char");
```

---

This can easily be expanded to any number of replacements, that would otherwise conflict. You can also add the `\b` code in the regular expression so that it only matches whole words (and not for example `a` inside `char`). Example:

```
str = Regex.Replace(str, @"\b(a|char|word|new|my|to)\b", m => {
  string s = m.Groups[0].Value;
  return
    s == "a" ? "new" :
    s == "char" ? "word" :
    s == "word" ? "char" :
    s == "new" ? "a" :
    s == "my" ? "mine" :
    "with";
});
```

Result:

```
"I'm new char. change mine word with a char"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have 3 glasses, the 1st and last glas are filled with water and the other one is empty, how can you replace the water from glas 1 to glas 3? It's the same way for your problem.

First change **word** to **to_replace** (for example), than change **char** to **word** and change again **to_replace** to **char**.

Comment: The principle is sound, but you need to use a character that isn't used anywhere else in the string. Using `w` gives the result `"I'm a char. change my charord to nechar char"`

Comment: Oke, I know that but the **w** is an example. You must use a char (or string) that isn't used.